# How to detect invalid Js cookie and remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, web-storage

I have set a cookie1 from `[.abcsite.com]`. when no domain mentioned from API it sets a cookie1 by default to `[www.abcsite.com]`. Now, the cookie1 gets duplicated, it creates issues in updating the value.  How to delete cookie1 with `[www.abcsite.com]` domain only when  cookie1 `[.abcsite.com]` domain is present as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {                   
    var date = new Date();                   
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + expiredays);                   
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ";expires="+date.toGMTString() + ";path=/";         
}
```

You can use this function to set a cookie and remove by :

```
setCookie(name, "", -1);
```

and the way to read cookie by:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0)     {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")           
        if (c_start != -1){ 
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1 
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start) 
            if (c_end == -1)   
                c_end = document.cookie.length   
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end))   
            } 
        } 
    return "" 
}
```

Comment: How to remove the cookie by checking the domain exists?

Comment: I add the getCookie in the answer